# Compile Error Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, compiler-errors

I have the following code and it will not compile.

```
public class P {
    private int num;
    P(int n) {
        this.num = n;
    }
}

public class Q extends P {
    private int i;
    public Q() {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Fix the second method so that it can compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the super constructor:

```
public Q() {
    super(42);  // <--
    i = 0;
}
```

You can read more about `super` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add default constructor in `P` to make it compile

```
P() {
  this.num = 0; // some default value
}
```

Comment: But I need to add in Q not P

Answer (score 0):

In the code the compiler write the super() keyword in the Q class that time control  will go the P class and it call the constructor, but P class has a parameter constructor.so you can add super() keyword with the any number because P class constructor has a parameter of int type.

```
  class P {
  private int num;
  P(int n) {
    this.num = n;
   }
  }
 public class Q extends P {
  private int i;
  public Q() {
    super(20);
    i = 0;
   }
     }
```